# updated permalink structure on localhost does not work

Tags: customization

I have a fresh localhost install and when i change the permalink structure from the default to any other structure the links break.  I have created new post under the new structure and it doesnt work.  When i change the structure i get the "Permalink Structure updated" alert but it does not work.  When i switch back to default, everything works.  I tried updating .htaccess to

```
 BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
 END WordPress
```

and nothing.    This is probably an easy fix.  Please help

Jim

Comment: What is your local server setup like?

Answer (score 1):

First thing I always do is change the permalinks back and forth to different settings a couple of times, which will cause them to flush and rewrite the rules.

Beyond that. what stack are you using? Where have you put the .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

if your testing server is on windows, try adding /index.php/ to your permalink structure while testing - this works for me.

Answer (score -1):

if you're using windows then .htaccess doesn't  work in localhost
because windows doesn't allow file without name and .htaccess have extention only no name.